# how to inject an array of Beans in spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

In Spring, we can inject a bean like bellowing code:

```java
    @Bean
    public AspectJExpressionPointcutAdvisor configurabledvisor() {
        System.out.println("configurabledvisor");
        AspectJExpressionPointcutAdvisor advisor = new AspectJExpressionPointcutAdvisor();
        advisor.setExpression(pointcut);
        advisor.setAdvice(new LogAroundAdvice());
        return advisor;
    }
```

In some situation, it is needed that an array of beans should be injected, the pseudo code like that:

```java
    @Bean[]
    public AspectJExpressionPointcutAdvisor[] configurabledvisorArray() {
        System.out.println("configurabledvisor");
        AspectJExpressionPointcutAdvisor advisor = new AspectJExpressionPointcutAdvisor();
        advisor.setExpression(pointcut);
        advisor.setAdvice(new LogAroundAdvice());
    
        AspectJExpressionPointcutAdvisor advisor1 = new AspectJExpressionPointcutAdvisor();
        advisor.setExpression(pointcut2);
        advisor.setAdvice(new AnotherAdvice());
        
        return new AspectJExpressionPointcutAdvisor[]{advisor, advisor1};
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Demo code address is: https://github.com/sluk3r/inject-multipleBeans/tree/main

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove the `[]`

```
@Bean
public AspectJExpressionPointcutAdvisor[] configurabledvisorArray() {
   ...
}
```

then you can inject (using autowire, constructor, setter, ...) your bean everywhere

```
@Autowire
private AspectJExpressionPointcutAdvisor[] configurabledvisorArray;
```

or as a dependency of another bean

```
@Bean
String testBean(AspectJExpressionPointcutAdvisor[] configurabledvisorArray){
   ...
}
```